# How can I configure exim to run a script for each e-mail

Tags: smtp, exim, exim4

I need to run a shell script under exim that can read each incoming e-mail, optionally rewrites them and then continues sending the email.

And ideal solution would be analogous to UNIX pipes:

```
cat *incoming email* | **some-script.sh** | *back to exim processing*
```

I want the script to run very early, so that I can for example change the destination address.

Is this possible with Exim, and how?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the router that use pipe transport with your script on the other side of pipe:

```
begin routers
preprocessor:
    driver      = accept
    condition   = if{ !eq{$header_X-Preproceeded}{yes}}
    transport   = myscript
    no_more

. . . . .

begin transports
myscript:
    driver      = pipe
    user        = scriptowner
    command     = /path/to/script --opt1 --opt2
```

If incoming message does not have `X-Preproceeded` header or its value doesn't set to `yes` then message is passed to the `myscript` transport. That is performed via piping `source | script` and all the message is passed to the script's `stdin`. After proceeding if you want to return proceeded message to the exim, you should add the `x-Preproceeded: yes` header to the message to prevent it to be routed to the next lap. Then you have to submit it via `sendmail` command.

```
#!/bin/sh
. . . . 
mandatory_empty_line = ''
cat << ENDOFTEXT | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
$headers
X_Preproceeded: yes
$mandatory_empty_line
$message_body
ENDOFTEXT
```

Keep in mind that effective user running script should be added to the trusted users by exim's config to allow sending from arbitrary address. Otherwise `exim` will replace any sender's address by `scriptowner@mydomain.tld`